# DOM interaction with Turboforms

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I need to go unsupported way and do some cosmetics on a form. Seems that from the onLoad method I'm not able to hack the DOM anymore. And looks that all the fields are not searchable either $("opportunityid_c") returns nothing. I was wandering if someone already managed to crack this.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to find the DOM-Node of the field with

```
parent.window.document.getElementById("opportunityid_c");
```

See [also](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2015/05/24/turbo-forms-get-your-javascript-ready-for-crm2015-update-1) at Impact on unsupported code